# Which Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi DLLs to use

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

If I create a blank project in VS 2013, I can add DLLs like System.Web.Http or System.Net.Http.Formatting from my local machine. These shipped with (or were automatically updated by) Visual Studio. But the version seems to be 4.0.0.0 even though I have all updates applied. Alternatively, I can get these DLLs from NuGet where the version is 5.2.0.0.

Other than "what the heck is going on?" - I guess my question is, why are my local files out of date if I have all updates applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.NET is no deployed by Nuget packages. By default VS have included MVC 4, but MVC 5 is available. That is way your local files were upgraded.

Comment: Is there any way to keep my local files up to date?